# Does knockback make creepers explode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Twice I've attacked a creeper with my sword, which has sharpness and knockback enchantments, and twice whilst still far away from me it's exploded.

Is this coincidence or does the knock back set the creeper off/not reset the distance from Steve?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's just a coincidence, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If someone has anecdotal experience either way, that's be great.

Comment: I've had this happen before without knockback enchantment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've just tested with a creeper spawner and a sword with knockback. Knockback is *not* the cause of the explosion.

What I think is happening to you is that the creeper is reaching the **creeper event horizon** - beyond which it *definitely will* explode, then you're hitting it. It's ending up miles away - much further away than it would be normally - then exploding.

Comment: Never heard of this event horizon — got a source?

Comment: There are actually two creeper event horizons - one is for starting fuse and another for cancelling. This is to make escaping a creeper explosion harder. I hope this radius is customizable with NBT anyway...